# Inflate a linear layout from R.id and not R.layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, viewgroup, inflate

I'm going nuts here. I have a layout for a fragment. Inside I have among other things a LinearLayout with an id, say for example myLinearLayout. Basically, I want to do the following:

```
LinearLayout newLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
LinearLayout layoutCopy = inflatefrom(R.id.myLinearLayout);
newLayout.addView(layoutCopy);
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

you can not inflate a `Layout` from its `R.id`, but you can inflate the `Layout` through `R.layout` and use the view returned to retrieve the `R.id` you need.

For instance

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);
LinearLayout layoutCopy = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout);
```

check for typo

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
View.inflate(Context, R.id, ViewGroup)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually blackbelt, that's pretty much how I solved it, but I still got error when adding the copied layout to the new layout. The reason was because the layout I wanted to copy still had a parent. Here's a complete sollution (layoutRoot is an xml layout that lives in res/layout and myLinearLayout is a LinearLayout inside the file layoutRoot. layoutToPlaceCopiedLayout is a LinearLayout inside the layout where I want to put the copied layout).

```
LinearLayout newLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutToPlaceCopiedLayout)
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
LinearLayout layoutRootCopy = (LinearLayout)inflatefrom(R.layout.layoutRoot);
LinearLayout layoutCopy = (LinearLayout)layoutRootCopy.findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout);
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)layoutCopy.getParent();
int index = parent.indexOfChild(layoutCopy);
parent.removeView(layoutCopy);
newLayout.addView(layoutCopy, index);
```